# Can I force GPU rendering on my MBP when connected to a power source?

Tags: ui, animation, macos, gpu

OS X Lion is quite demanding for old Macs. Even though I own a 15'' MBP early 2011 with the 'powerful' Intel HD 3000 for *integrated* graphics, some animations just don't feel right (low fps).

This is especially very noticeable with Mission Control: It's **choppy**.

When ever *discrete* graphics are being used (e.g. QuickTime movie with GPU acceleration, Win7 in VirtualBox...) Mission Control is much smoother and easier on the eye.

#### Question:

- Is it possible to force discrete graphics to be used when the MBP is connected to a power source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [gfxCardStatus](http://codykrieger.com/gfxCardStatus) (free)

I found the link to it on [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-unibody-faq/macbook-pro-unibody-switching-between-graphics-processors.html) along with some other info about graphics switching.

- fast access via menu icon
- auto/manually switch between discrete and integrated graphics
- power source-based switching
- growl support
- open source

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. And thanks for editing my answer to make it better! :-)

Comment: This program has helped many get better battery life, better performance and more importantly achieve a more stable system in the case where a specific program has issues (crashes) when the graphics card switches or is one mode over the other. A great tool to have in your toolbox if you like optimizing things.

Comment: This feature has been removed.

Comment: This does not appear to work on 10.10