# Is there a way to only enable automatic graphics switching when on battery power?

Tags: battery, gpu

It is rare when I use my MBP on battery power. But is there a way to only enable **[automatic graphics switching](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4110)** when on battery power?

Comment: Take a look at [can i force gpu rendering on my mbp when connected to a power source](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40423/can-i-force-gpu-rendering-on-my-mbp-when-connected-to-a-power-source/40425#40425). Its similar (but not the same) so might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an application called "gfxCardStatus" :)

Comment: Not anymore; gfxCardStatus has removed that feature.

Answer (score -1):

"is there a way to only enable automatic graphics switching when on battery power?"

Yes.

Go to System Preferences -> Energy Saver 
There are two tabs at the top of the window; one for battery and one for AC power.

Set the graphics switching option by checking or un-checking "Automatic Graphics Switching" in those tabs.

Comment: Sure, but the "Automatic Graphics Switching" checkbox is outside, meaning that it's a global setting.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate.  No reason to keep it.